# How to get content from next node

Tags: xpath

I have an XML below -

```
<document>
  <node name="Node 0 Text here" ID="01" >aa
  </node>
  <node name="Node 1 Text here" ID="11">bb
  </node>
  <node name="Node 2 Text here" ID="12">cc
  </node>
  <node name="Node 3 Text here" ID="22">dd
  </node>
  <node name="Node 4 Text here" ID="23">ee
  </node>
</document>
```

I need to search content in a particular node within this XML. 
If search keyword does not exist in that node, then I have to begin searching from the next node of current node, you could say sibling.
  If that keyword does not exist in all the nodes after the current node then it should begin search from start..

I have to achieve this in my code behind- dotnet class. I have used -

```
 XmlNodeList xmlNodes = xd.SelectNodes("//12/following-sibling::*");
```

Here, 12 refers to nodeid of the current node,which will be passed as an argument. But I am getting error.
  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I have accepted answers to all  my questions so far. Please let me know what else to do?

Comment: You said you had an xpath expression, but couldn't get it right.  Could you show us what you tried?

Comment: I used- XmlNodeList xmlNodes = xd.SelectNodes("//12/following-sibling::*"); Here, 12 refers to nodeid of the current node,which will be passed as an argument.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete, one-liner-XPath-expression solution and for an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

> > *I need to search content in a particular node within this XML*

to get a node matching by its content, the XPath is:

```
 node[contains(text(),'aa')]
```

This will return the first node for example and any other node whose content text contains `aa`.

> > *If search keyword does not exist in that node, then I have to begin searching from the next node of current node, you could say sibling. If that keyword does not exist in all the nodes after the current node then it should begin search from start.*

This sentence does not make much sense to XPath. The expression above will return all nodes matching the keyword. If you want the first matched node you can get it from the `XmlNodeList` after or directly from the XPath expression changing it to:

```
node[contains(text(),'aa')][1]
```

> > *12 refers to nodeid of the current node,which will be passed as an argument*

That's not correct. To select the node by id you should use, for instance:

```
node[@id=12]/text()
```

This will get the content of the node with `id=12`.

Answer (score 0):

**Use**:

```
  (/*/node[ID='12']/following-sibling::*[contains(.,$pattern)][1]
  |
   /*/node[ID='12']/preceding-sibling::*[contains(.,$pattern)][1]
  )
   [last()]
```

This expression selects the last from the two wanted selections -- the first of the following siblings that contains the value of `$pattern` and the first of the preceding siblings that contains the value of `$pattern`.

You need to substitute `$pattern` with the exact value you want to serch for.